# message.ID of peeked MSMQ message somehow gets lost

Tags: c#, .net, msmq

I've got some old code, peeking messages from a MSMQ using `BeginPeek`/`EndPeek`. Directly after peeking it compares the ID of the message successfully:

```
if (message.Id != _lastMessageID) { // ... }
```

Later in the code `message.Id` is passed to the `ReceiveById` method. This works most of the time, however, sporadically there is an exception thrown at exact this position:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Property Label was not retrieved
>   when receiving the message

So sometimes somehow `message.Id` seems to get lost in the meanwhile. Does anybody know about a behavior like this? Or has any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I've encountered this problem in the past.  The problem was with my code calling BeginPeek twice, which resulted in the PeekCompleted event being thrown twice, with the same message each time.  Check the message Id's to see if the message that produced the error was already received at an earlier point in time by your app.  I had to print out the message id as the first step in my PeekComplete event handler to catch this.  You have to be very careful not to call BeginPeek if a call to Begin Peek has already been made and has not returned.